# Repurpose ADT sensors

Tags: samsung-smartthings, sensors, home-security

My wife and I just purchased a new house and the ADT Security sensors were still installed, but no keypad panel. After speaking with a Rep on pricing and logistics, we decided not to continue the service. I asked about the existing hardware and the Rep said that should we decide to continue service we can continue to use the existing hardware, otherwise someone can come and uninstall it. Anyways, I requested them to uninstall the hardware about a month and a half ago with no further response. So, as far as I can tell, I now have 3 Honeywell door sensors and 1 Honeywell Motion Detector (still installed).

I'm curious if there is any way to include these sensors with my Samsung SmartThings system? Would it be as simple as adding/changing a wireless component to a compatible signal with ZigBee/Z-Wave/Bluetooth/etc.?

**Update**:

The model number for the entire unit seems to be ***A 026-0934***, however I couldn't find it in the [catalogue mentioned in the comments](http://sensing.honeywell.com/). There are several other model numbers it looks like, [mostly referring to what appears to be a safety switch](http://sensing.honeywell.com/index.php?ci_id=159835&la_id=1&No=0&Nrpp=50&Ntt=X%20315%20AC&Page=1) to cut off power when the unit is opened.

- The product page is here: [Honeywell 5816 Wireless Door Sensor and Window](https://www.alarmgrid.com/products/honeywell-5816)
- [Reusing/recycling a Petzi Treat Camera?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/70/reusing-recycling-a-petzi-treat-camera) seems related.

Comment: Found this project that might answer your question! enjoy https://denglend.github.io/decode345/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That particular sensor is using RF 345 MHz and is not compatible with SmartThings. To connect the sensor directly to the SmartThings hub it would to be Zwave, Zigbee, or Lan Connected; it would also require a supported device type handler.

There are methods of connecting third party alarm sensors to the SmartThings. I don't have any direct experience with these and I cannot make a recommendation on them.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the information provided so far, it can be concluded that ADT and Honeywell have provided a good home security system. Why? There is no public technical infomation on the wireless transmitter used in Honeywell 5816 Wireless window and door sensors.

It looks like Honeywell has white labeled the wireless door and window sensor from [Ademco Security](http://ademcosecurity.com/)

**Available options:**

Based on the below snippet it looks like the window and door sensor is using a *magnetic reed switch*.

[[image: Ademco Wireless Transmitter[2]]

It might be fairly simple to develop a simple electronic circuit to probe the reed switch and transmit the data to the SmartThings system.

Looking at the Samsung SmartThings Multipurpose Sensor it looks like they might be using a magnatic reed switch.

[image: Smartthings Sensor]

So from a cost and time standpoint you might be better off purchasing a SmartThings multipurpose sensor and ditch the Honeywell sensor.

**References**

- [5816 Wireless-Transmitter](http://library.ademconet.com/MWT/fs2/5816/Wireless-Transmitter-(Specification-Sheet).PDF)
- [Samsung SmartThings Multipurpose Sensor](https://support.smartthings.com/hc/en-us/articles/205382174-Samsung-SmartThings-Multipurpose-Sensor)
- [SmartSense Multi User Guide](https://support.smartthings.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/200320430/SmartSense_Multi_User_Guide.pdf)

Comment: +1 for the breakdown. I already have a few of the SmartThings multi-sensors. But we just moved into the house and it had these Honeywell sensors already installed, so I was hoping to use them in conjunction with SmartThings. I still might poke around and use them as a project, just to see if I can "hack" it.

Answer (score 2):

Give this [one](https://community.smartthings.com/t/connect-wired-alarm-system-sensors-to-smartthings-with-a-nodemcu-esp8266-deprecated/76010) a try.

It is talking about connecting your old wired sensor endpoints from the Alarm panel to Smartthings. There might be something that you can get from reading the post.