# Make ADT Door Sensors work with Ring security system?

Tags: sensors, home-security, door-sensor

Is there a way to modify ADT's Window and/or thin Door sensors in some way to work as door sensors for Ring's Home Security System?

I am transitioning from an ADT security system to Ring's, but am not keen on buying Ring's door sensors for $20 each to replace ADT's.

This should be one of the sensors (by visual): [Door](https://www.alarmgrid.com/products/2gig-dw10-345).
(I will update if I find the other sensor.)

([This SE:IoT question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/191/repurpose-adt-sensors) was similar, but is for the Samsung SmartThings. The problem was that the sensor used 345 MHz - incompatible.)

(Also asking on SE:HomeAutomation - I am not sure which forum is most relevant.)

Comment: Please do not cross post the same questions to multiple SE sites. If the question if not suitable for a site the moderators can move it, but cross posing splits responses.

Comment: Just an aside: this site is effectively the Home Automation Stack Exchange (as well as more industrial uses of IoT)—you asked on *Home Improvement* (DIY) where I don't think it will be on-topic. It's perfectly on-topic here, though.

Comment: Can you provide more data about the sensors, and anything that leads you to believe there may be enough in common between the two vendor's standards?